# How to prove $\sum_{k=1}^n{n\choose k}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$?

Tags: harmonic-numbers, digamma-function

I think by induction we can do it. Let
$I(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n{n\choose k}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}.$ Then, we must show that $I(n+1)-I(n)=\frac{1}{n+1}$.

$\begin{align} 
I(n+1)-I(n)&=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}+\sum_{k=1}^n\left({n+1\choose k}-{n\choose k}\right)\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}\\
&=I(n+1)-I(n)=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}+\sum_{k=1}^n{n\choose k-1}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n{n+1\choose k}(-1)^{k}\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}+\frac{(-1)^n+1}{n+1}\\
&=\frac{1}{n+1}
\end{align}$

I saw these steps now. If you don't write you can't see anything. Thanks for help and elementary proofs.

[WA says](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum_%28k%3D1%29%5En%20%28-1%29%5E%28k%2B1%29*C%28n%2Ck%29%2Fk) it is about Digamma function. What is the connection? These are very hot topics for students like me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I will say that a more elementary proof of this statement, in the style of your attempt, does exist. Here is a [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4533509/an-interesting-sum-identity-sum-frac-1-k-1-cdots-k-m-sum-k-1n-frac/4533615#4533615) of a generalization of this identity I authored a while back, in case you're interested.

Comment: @C-RAM Thanks I will try it.

Comment: For a standard non-elementary solution (i.e. using calculus) see chapter 2 in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start with the generating function

$$(1 + x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} x^k.$$

We want to modify this so that the $x^k$ term becomes $(-1)^{k+1} x^{k-1}$, so that we can integrate it. This means the LHS is

$$I_n = \int_0^1 \frac{1 - (1 - x)^n}{x} \, dx.$$

Now perform the substitution $u = 1 - x$, which gives

$$I_n = \int_0^1 \frac{1 - u^n}{1 - u} \, du = \int_0^1 \left( 1 + u + \dots + u^{n-1} \right) \, du = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} = H_n$$

which is the RHS, as desired.

---

An alternative argument, also using generating functions, in a different way. We need the following general facts: if a sequence $\{ a_k \}$ has generating function $A(x) = \sum a_k x^k$, then

1. The generating function of the partial sums $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k$ is $\frac{1}{1 - x} A(x)$, and
2. The generating function of the binomial sums $\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} a_k$ is $\frac{1}{1 - x} A \left( \frac{x}{1 - x} \right)$ (this is a nice exercise).

Now, the generating function of the sequence $\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}$ is $\ln (1 + x)$, and the generating function of the sequence $\frac{1}{k}$ is $\ln \frac{1}{1 - x}$. This gives that the generating function of the LHS is

$$\frac{1}{1 - x} \ln \left( 1 + \frac{x}{1 - x} \right) = \frac{1}{1 - x} \ln \frac{1}{1 - x}$$

which is also the generating function of the RHS.

Comment: Elementary... Thanks.

Comment: Is this a Mobius transformation?

Comment: The bit on the inside is, yes.

Answer (score 5):

You got off to a good start. Now use

$$
\binom n{k-1}\frac1k=\binom{n+1}k\frac1{n+1}\;
$$

to obtain

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=1}^n\binom n{k-1}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}k
&=&
\sum_{k=1}^n\binom {n+1}k\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{n+1}
\\
&=&
\frac1{n+1}\left(1-(-1)^n-\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom {n+1}k(-1)^k\right)
\\
&=&
\frac1{n+1}\left(1-(-1)^n-(1+(-1))^{n+1}\right)\\
&=&
\frac1{n+1}-(-1)^n\frac1{n+1}\;.
\end{eqnarray}

You have the wrong sign on your $n+1$ term; if you correct that, it cancels with the second term here, leaving $\frac1{n+1}$ as required.

Comment: +1 This is the only elementary solution up to now here.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^{a}}=\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k-1}\int_0^1 \frac{(-1)^{a-1}}{(a-1)!} x^{k-1}\ln^{a-1}(x)dx$$

$$=\frac{(-1)^{a-1}}{(a-1)!}\int_0^1\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}(-x)^{k-1}\right)\ln^{a-1}(x)dx$$

$$=\frac{(-1)^{a-1}}{(a-1)!}\int_0^1\left(\frac{1-(1-x)^n}{x}\right)\ln^{a-1}(x)dx$$

$$\overset{1-x\to x}{=}\frac{(-1)^{a-1}}{(a-1)!}\int_0^1\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\ln^{a-1}(1-x)dx$$

$$\overset{IBP}{=}\frac{(-1)^a n}{a!}\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\ln^a(1-x)dx$$

$$=\frac{(-1)^a n}{a!} t(a,n)$$

where

$$t(a,n)=\lim_{m\to1}\frac{\partial^a}{\partial m^a}\operatorname{B}(m,n)$$

$$=(-1)^a(a-1)!\left[\frac{H_n^{(a)}}{n}+\sum_{j=1}^{a-1}\frac{(-1)^j}{j!}H_n^{(a-j)}t(j,n)\right],\quad a=1,2,3...$$

For $a=1$,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}=-nt(1,n)=H_n$$

For $a=2$,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^2}=\frac{n}2 t(2,n)=\frac{1}2\left(H_n^2+H_n^{(2)}\right)$$

For $a=3$,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^3}=-\frac{n}6t(3,n)=\frac{1}6\left(H_n^3+3H_nH_n^{(2)}+2H_n^{(3)}\right)$$

For $a=4$,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^4}=\frac{n}{24} t(4,n)=\frac{1}{24}\left(H_n^4+6H_n^2H_n^{(2)}+8H_nH_n^{(3)}+3(H_n^{(2)})^2+6H_n^{(4)}\right)$$

Comment: Kink's property

Comment: I generalized it .. hope you find it helpful

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see the [Newton series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) (sometimes called Stern series) of Digamma function:
$$\psi(s+1)=-\gamma+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{s\choose k}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\tag{1}$$
and we also have
$$\psi(s+1)=-\gamma+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{s+k}\tag{2}$$
Let $s=n$ and the result follows by rearrangment of the second series.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n\geq 1$ and define the sequence,
$$ a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k} \frac{1}{k} (-1)^{k+1} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {n\choose k} \frac{1}{k} (-1)^{k+1} $$
(If $k>n$ then the binomial coefficient is zero, not changing the sum).

The generating function of this sequence is equal to,
$$ A(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n x^n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {n\choose k} \frac{1}{k} (-1)^{k+1} x^n  = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} \left\{ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {n\choose k} x^n \right\}$$
The series in the bracket is a variant of the geometric series and is well-known to sum to,
$$ A(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} \left\{ \frac{x^k}{(1-x)^{k+1}} \right\} = \frac{1}{1-x}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} \left( \frac{x}{1-x} \right)^k  $$
The remaining series is again well-known to sum of the logarithmic series, therefore,
$$ A(x) = \frac{1}{1-x} \log \left( 1 + \frac{x}{1-x} \right) = \frac{1}{1-x} \log \left( \frac{1}{1-x} \right) $$
Now recall that $\log(\tfrac{1}{\theta}) = -\log(\theta)$, therefore, by using logarithmic series again,
$$ A(x) = \frac{1}{1-x} \bigg( -\log(1-x) \bigg) = \frac{1}{1-x}\left( \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k} \right) = \left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k \right) \left( \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k} \right)$$
Now it is easy to find the $x^n$ coefficient of $A(x)$, it is equal to,
$$ a_n = \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n-1} + ... + \frac{1}{1} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} $$

Comment: Nice, variant of geometric series.