# Find $\sum^{n}_{k=1} \binom{n}{k} \frac{(-1)^k}{k^a}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, harmonic-numbers, stirling-numbers

I have been trying to find a general representation of the following finite sum.

$$
S(n,a) = -\sum^{n}_{k=1} \binom{n}{k} \frac{(-1)^k}{k^a}
$$

The sum seems to be related to Generalized Harmonic Numbers, as I've been able to work out the first few integer values of $a$  as the following.

$$
S(n,1) = H_{n} \ , \ S(n,2) = \frac{(H_{n})^{2} + H_{n}^{(2)}}{2} \ , \ S(n,3) = \frac{(H_{n})^3}{6} + \frac{H_{n}^{(2)}H_{n}}{2} + \frac{H_{n}^{(3)}}{3}
$$

Where $ H_{n}^{(m)}$ is the n-th m-th order generalized harmonic number. It also sees to be closely related to the Stirling numbers of the second kind because if you take $a$ to be negative you get something very close to the explicit definition of the stirling numbers. I have looked online to see if there is any identities related to these special numbers and function that involve a sum like this but I haven't been able to find anything. If you have any insight please let me know.

Comment: Define $$S(n,a;x)=-\sum_{k=1}^{n}{n\choose k}\frac{(-1)^k}{k^a}x^k.$$ Then it follows that $$x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}S(n,a;x)=S(n,a-1;x)$$

Comment: Could you show us how you obtained those results?

Comment: @clathratus its not anything special I literally just put it into wolfram alpha pro and did some simplification and factoring by hand. The first one however is a well known identity of the harmonic numbers that is on the wikepedia page even.

Comment: @clathratus I did find through your idea of generalizing to a polynomial, which I did not think of doing, that $S(n,a,x) = nx {}_{a+2}F_{a+1}(1^{(a+1)}, 1-n; 2^{(a+1)}; x)$ which is very close to the hypergeometric definition of the Polylogirithm which is an interesting lead.

Comment: $$
\exp \bigg( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{H_n^{(k)} }}{k}x^k } } \bigg) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {S(n,k)x^k } 
$$

Comment: @Garry that makes sense in light of the bell polynomials of the generalized harmonic numbers being equal to the sum, but that is very cool.

Comment: @Gary How do you get that? I get 
$$\sum_{\alpha\ge0}S(n,\alpha)x^\alpha=-\sum_{\alpha\ge0}\sum_{j=1}^{n}{n\choose j}\frac{(-1)^j}{j^\alpha}x^\alpha=-\sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^j{n\choose j}\sum_{\alpha\ge0}(x/j)^\alpha=\sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^j{n\choose j}\frac{x}{x-j}$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall the complete symmetric function in $n$ variables:
$$
h_{n,k}:=h_{n,k}(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\sum_{1\le i_1\le \dots \le i_k \le n} x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\cdots x_{i_k} 
$$
Note that this satisfies the recurrence
$$
\begin{align}
h_{n,k}&=h_{n-1,k}+x_n\cdot h_{n,k-1}\tag1
\\
h_{n,0}&=1 \quad (n>0)
\\
h_{0,k}&=0 \quad (k>0)
\end{align}
$$
The recurrence in $(1)$ uniquely defines the bivariate sequence $h_{n,k}$.

> **Claim:** For all $n,a\in \mathbb N$ where $n>0$ or $a>0$, $$ 
> S(n,a)=h_{n,a}(1,\tfrac12,\tfrac13,\dots,\tfrac1n)
> $$

*Proof:*
To prove this, note that
$$
\begin{align}
S(n,a)
&= \sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i-1}\binom {n-1}{i}i^{-a}&+&&&\sum_{i=1}^{n}(-1)^{i-1}\binom{n-1}{i-1}i^{-a}
\\
&= S(n-1,a)&+&&&\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i-1}\binom {n-1}{i-1}\cdot \frac{n}{i}\cdot i^{-(a-1)}
\\
&= S(n-1,a)&+&&&\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i-1}\binom {n}{i}\cdot i^{-(a-1)}
\\
&=S(n-1,a)&+&&&\tfrac 1nS(n, a-1)
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, letting $x_n=\frac1n$ for each $n\ge 1$, we see $S(n,a)$ satisfies the exact same recurrence and base cases as $(1)$. This gives a proof that $S(n,a)=h_{n,a}(1^{-1},2^{-2},\dots,n^{-1})$ by induction on $n+a$.
$\tag*{$\square$}$

Using [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Expressing_complete_homogeneous_symmetric_polynomials_in_terms_of_power_sums), we can express the homogenous symmetric polynomials in terms of the power sum polynomials $p_{n,k}$, which evaluated at $1,\frac12,\dots,\frac1n$ is just the generalized Harmonic numbers, $H_{n,k}$.
$$
S(n,a)=h_{n,a}= \sum_{\lambda |- a} P(\text{random $\pi\in S_a$ has cycle type $\lambda$}) \prod_{i=1}^{\text{len}(\lambda)}H_{n, \lambda_i}
$$
For example,
$$
\begin{align}
S(n,4)&=\frac1{4!}\big(\quad 1\cdot (H_{n,1})^4
&& \text{1 permutation with cycle type $(1,1,1,1)$}
\\
&\hspace{1.3cm} + 6\cdot (H_{n,1})^2\cdot H_{n,2}
&& \text{6 permutations with cycle type $(2,1,1)$}
\\
&\hspace{1.3cm} + 3\cdot (H_{n,2})^2
&& \text{3 permutations with cycle type $(2,2)$}
\\
&\hspace{1.3cm} + 8\cdot H_{n,1}\cdot H_{n,3}
&& \text{8 permutations with cycle type $(3,1)$}
\\
&\hspace{1.3cm} + 6\cdot H_{n,4}\big)
&& \text{6 permutations with cycle type $(4)$}
\end{align}
$$
As $n\to\infty$, the dominant term is always the identity permutation, so we get $S(n,a)\sim \frac{(\log n)^a}{a!}$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: That is a beutiful proof. I never would have thaought to first begin with the symetric function. Wonderful!

Answer (score 2):

The following solution is already given in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4628455) but I am providing more details here:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^{a}}=\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k-1}\int_0^1 \frac{(-1)^{a-1}}{(a-1)!} x^{k-1}\ln^{a-1}(x)dx$$
$$=\frac{(-1)^{a-1}}{(a-1)!}\int_0^1\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}(-x)^{k-1}\right)\ln^{a-1}(x)dx$$
$$=\frac{(-1)^{a-1}}{(a-1)!}\int_0^1\left(\frac{1-(1-x)^n}{x}\right)\ln^{a-1}(x)dx$$
$$\overset{1-x\to x}{=}\frac{(-1)^{a-1}}{(a-1)!}\int_0^1\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\ln^{a-1}(1-x)dx$$
$$\overset{IBP}{=}\frac{(-1)^a n}{a!}\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\ln^a(1-x)dx$$
$$=\frac{(-1)^a n}{a!}\lim_{m\to1}\frac{\partial^a}{\partial m^a}\operatorname{B}(m,n)$$
$$=\frac{(-1)^a n}{a!} t(a,n).$$
Let's find the derivative of the beta function,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial m}\operatorname{B}(m,n)=\frac{\partial}{\partial m}\frac{\Gamma(m)\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(m+n)}$$
$$=\Gamma(m)\frac{\Gamma(m+n)\Gamma(n)\psi(n)-\Gamma(m+n)\psi(m+n)\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma^2(m+n)}$$
$$=-\frac{\Gamma(m)\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(m+n)}(\psi(m+n)-\psi(n))$$
$$=-\operatorname{B}(m,n)(\psi(m+n)-\psi(n))=-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\operatorname{B}(m,n)}{k+m}.$$
Taking the $a$-th derivative, we find
$$\frac{\partial^a}{{\partial m}^{a}}\operatorname{B}(m,n)={(-1)}^a(a-1)!\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\operatorname{B}(m,n)}{(k+m)^{a}}+\sum_{j=1}^{a-1}\frac{{(-1)}^{a-j}}{j!}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\frac{\partial^j}{{\partial m}^{j}}\operatorname{B}(m,n)}{{(k+m)}^{a-j}}\right).$$
Let $m\to1$ and remember $\displaystyle\lim_{m\to1}\frac{\partial^a}{{\partial m}^{a}}\operatorname{B}(m,n)=t(a,n)$
observing that
$$\lim_{m\to1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{{(k+m)}^r}=H_n^{(r)};\quad \lim_{m\to1}\operatorname{B}(m,n)=\frac{1}{n},$$
we get
$$t(a,n)={(-1)}^a(a-1)!\left(\frac{H_n^{(a)}}{n}+\sum_{j=1}^{a-1}\frac{{(-1)}^{j}}{j!}H_n^{(a-j)}t(j,n)\right).$$

---

Examples:

For $a=1$,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}=-nt(1,n)=H_n$$

For $a=2$,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^2}=\frac{n}2 t(2,n)=\frac{1}2\left(H_n^2+H_n^{(2)}\right)$$

For $a=3$,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^3}=-\frac{n}6t(3,n)=\frac{1}6\left(H_n^3+3H_nH_n^{(2)}+2H_n^{(3)}\right)$$

For $a=4$,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^4}=\frac{n}{24} t(4,n)=\frac{1}{24}\left(H_n^4+6H_n^2H_n^{(2)}+8H_nH_n^{(3)}+3(H_n^{(2)})^2+6H_n^{(4)}\right)$$

Comment: This is great. Im surprised I never found that awnser in the post you linked. I scoured the internet everywhere I could, maybe because it was a tangential awnser to the original post. Ironically I came upon the sum in my work trying to solve the integral in line 5 of your initial transformations. I guess I should have gone down a seperate path.